# How is a sender verified with Gmail's 'Send Mail As' feature?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, spf

I have an email account info@example.com with mail.live.com .

I also have a Gmail account. I have set up the 'Send mail as' feature in Gmail to send mail as  info@example.com, and this works correctly.

My question is, if I send an email from Gmail 'as' info@example.com, how does the recipient's server verify that Gmail was authorized to send mail for example.com?

I have some knowledge of SPF records, and I know that the SPF record for example.com says that only messages originating from hotmail.com servers are valid.

The message that Gmail sends out has the @gmail.com address in the Return-Path and Sender fields, and so the SPF check is done against gmail.com and not example.com.

I have tested this with the test service at verifier.port25.com and it passes.

```
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, if I send an email from Gmail 'as' info@example.com, how does the recipient's server verify that Gmail was authorized to send mail for example.com?

It would check the SPF record, which would indicate a failure and thus a higher spamminess score. If you're going to be sending from Gmail, you should have Gmail in the SPF.

Comment: I don't have Gmail in the SPF, but it still passes checks by verifier.port25.com, so I think that there is something else going on.

Comment: How about you give us the domain and some example e-mail headers, then? Hard for us to help you troubleshoot `example.com`.